# Is it halal to earning profit from reselling shoes?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I'm a Muslim concerned about my profit makings. I purchase shoes online from Adidas or clothing items from Nike or Supreme and resell them to make profit. I usually list them for the price they resell for. Is this haram or halal because I want to be enjoy doing something that is halal. My age is 14 and thanks if you answer my question.

Comment: It might depend on where you live, according to the law of that country.. Are you allowed to sell the items by the brand companies? And some schools of thought will differ according to how much you may profit per item. But generally speaking it should be halal to sell shoes.